# comparing Decimal(9,3) column value in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a column pointsAwarded decimal(9,3) and I have the following LInq

```
db.TableName.Select(x=>x.pointsAwarded >0)
```

The fact is that it is not filtering the data and returning me the whole result set.
How to compare it?
I tried with `x.pointsAwarded.value>0` and `x.pointsAwarded.value>0.000` and

```
x.pointsAwarded > (Decimal?)0
```

but with no luck.
Pls help

Comment: Try `Where` instead of `Select`

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius that should be an answer

Comment: By using `Select` you make a mapping from the list of decimals to a list of booleans. You're not filtering at all.

Comment: `.Select(x => x.pointsAwarded > 0)` creates IEnumerable of bool values, for each value in your Table there's true if `x.pointsAwarded > 0` and false otherwise. If you want to filter your collection, use Where method like @AndriusNaruševičius suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `Where` instead of a `Select`

```
db.TableName.Where(x=>x.pointsAwarded > 0)
```

**UPDATE:**

This answer has been given more credit than it previously deserved, so I will elaburete a little
The `Where` statement acts as the filter. It determins whitch elements the returned list should contain.
The `Select` statement is the projection of the elements. Given a list of elements, how would you like them presented.